# React videochat screenshare

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I am new to WebRTC and trying to build a video chat. At the moment, all the functionality is implemented except for screen sharing. I took the React video chat example and upgrade it. Of course, I can turn on the screen sharing itself and it is shown at the host, but not transmitted to another users.

https://github.com/rRaijin/video-chat-webrtc

Tell me, please, is it necessary to use socket.emit in the case of sharing and process it for recipients, or should some method be called on RTCPeerConnection instance?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary to use  socket.emit
I think you need   RTCPeerConnection instance

https://webrtc-promocm.herokuapp.com/

in my demo above you can add and remove screen and video with both participants alongs with audio.

it uses rtcmulticonnection library

Answer (score 0):

A socket is useful to pass the data from server to client. In this case, it is necessary to use Socket.

**What does socket exactly do?**

If you have a call now and Disconnect buttons, now if you click on the call now button then it becomes disabled and the Disconnect button become enabled.

But this process has become only in your system but in the Client system in which you are calling, the call now button will remain enabled and the disconnect button remain disabled.

Now the Socket will be used here, the socket will pass the value in real-time and will disable the call now button and enable the disconnect button in both systems.

**Note-1:** Please Consider your system as a Server From where you are trying to call and another system as the Client.

**Note-2:** You can use Peerjs instead of Socket.